# Where is the option to "get everything" when opening a solution in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In previous versions of visual studio there was an option to "Get everything when a solution or project is opened"

In Visual Studio 2013 it is the first option in the Source Control Environment settings:
[image: Visual Studio 2013 Source Control Environment Settings]

Does this option exist in Visual Studio 2015?  If not, is there another way to automatically get the latest version when opening the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature was removed last minute as it had a major negative impact on the dynamic solution loading process which speeds up opening large solutions in Visual studio 2015.

Quote [from the Product Group here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1907270f-d513-4fb7-b3c5-1966743c30c1/get-everything-when-a-solution-or-project-is-opened-in-vs2015?forum=tfsversioncontrol):

> Late in the ship cycle, we found that the async project load improvements caused a fairly large issue with this feature.  Namely, if you had this feature enabled, you were very likely to see VS deadlock if it tried to get sources while also asynchronously loading projects.  Given that this feature is, in general, a bad practice, and fixing it would have been a fairly significant investment, we decided to remove it.

If you need an alternative, then it's better to create a little batch script or powershell script that uses the tf commandline to get the latest version before opening the solution:

```
tf get . /recursive /version:T
start solutionfile.sln
```

That way the solution is up to date before Visual Studio starts parsing it.

I can imagine a few reasons which would make this a "bad practice", mostly when working with more than one developer:

- It could require conflict resolution and thus really interfere with the loading process
- It could have you bring in changes from others that break your local workspace